# How to pass in filename as a parameter and opening it properly?

Tags: c++

```
void openfile(const string &db_filename) {
    ifstream file;
    file.open("db_filename");
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        cout<<"true"<<endl;
    }
    else cout<<"false"<<endl;}
```

I have this simple code here that checks if file is open. However, whenever I run this, I get false. which means that the file is not open. I dont know why but Im sure that the files are in the same folder and the file name is entered correctly. Is there anything wrong with this code?

Comment: file.open(db_filename);

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string literal `"db_filename"` to `open()` instead of passing your `db_filename` string object. Simply remove the quotes:

```
file.open(db_filename);
```

If your version of the STL doesn't support passing a `std::string` to `open()`, call the string's `c_str()` method instead:

```
file.open(db_filename.c_str());
```